# Parameters list send to Event Listener Function in sipml5

Tags: webrtc, asterisk, sipml

Did any one know the parameter list(other than type and session) send to the event listener function when an event occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Following event parameters and there values :
 1) e.type => event type such as connected,started,i_new_call,I_new_message,terminated 
 2) e.session => current event session 
 3) e.getSipResponseCode() => event response code(-1,100,180,603,200,487) 
 4) e.description => event description
 5) e.getContentString() => vent content string(i think only for i_notify event) 
 6) e.getContentType() => event content type(i think only for i_notify event)